# Help: creating secure keys

Tags: encryption

I want to encrypt my mails and sign them with my digital signaure. I just don't know how/where I get it.

1. what is a good/trustworthy CA?
2. how do I generate those keys?
3. I wanna use EC, which length, which curve, how?

Pretend I am dumb and really wanna be more secure in my everyday. And wanna sign some contracts with digital signature.

PS! I use Arch Linux. And I wanna do it all for free if possible.

Comment: Err, [GnuPG](https://gnupg.org/)? Very free. What's the CA for?

Comment: Certificate Authority. I would like to give a digital signature on PDFs signing them this way.

Comment: Yes I know ;-)  A digital signature for email doesn't really require a CA. They're more appropriate for HTTPS comms. Check out my link as it's free. Decent CA's aren't. Exception: Let’s Encrypt, but they're weird.

Comment: Let's Encrypt doesn't deliver certs for signature generation it seems, just authentication. The use of PGP for mail seems the most appropriate, although it is not as useful as it was. Signing PDF's goes in the direction of non-repudiation, that's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, à la what a CA traditionally does. I considered it for my site, but the weirdness is too much :-( Plus old Zooey doesn't need the crypto overhead; he's tired.